# CSV data not parsed correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, csv, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to import some CSV data but for some reason they are not structured correctly and contain invalid characters. So for example, when I do `sale_hash["location"]` it returns `nil`.

Here is the function I am using:

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, encoding:'iso-8859-1') do |row|
    sale_hash = row.to_hash
    p sale_hash
  end
end
```

I get something like this:

```
{
  "date;day;time;location;station;washer;plate_number;O;I;W;total_price;;;;"
    => "23/04/16;SATURDAY;15:11;ALPHAMEGA LIN;GROUNDFLOOR;NIKOLAS APOSTOLIDES;KKY333;YES;NO;NO;Û2",
  nil => "95;;;;"
}
```

All I did was take an excel spreadsheet and export it to CSV. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you exported it with semicolon delimiters. The CSV library defaults to comma delimiters.

Comment: where do i change that?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Answer (score 0):

Right so thanks to Jordan and mu is too short, I got it working by adding the following `col_sep`:

```
def self.import(file)
  csv = CSV.read(file.path, headers: true, col_sep: ";")

  csv.each do |row|
    sale_hash = row.to_hash
    p sale_hash
  end
end
```